# Qual status code usar quando não há registro do banco para retornar numa requisição HTTP?

Tags: php, api, rest, http, http-status

Eu possuo um endpoint que retorna uma lista de produtos.

Sendo assim, se houver dados desta lista eu defino o status code do HTTP para 200, e se não houver, eu retorno apenas um json dizendo que nenhum registro foi encontrado e com o status code do HTTP 200.

Meu endpoint:

```
http://api.minhaappexemplo.com.br/rest/lista/1/minha111chave222
```

Minha rotina responsável por este endpoint, veja:

```
<?php  
$app->get('/rest/lista/{id}/{key}', 
    function(\Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface $request, \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $response, $next)
    {
        $id = $request->getAttribute("id");

        $listaProdutos = Lista::obterListaProdutos($id);

        if ($listaProdutos)
        {            
            return $response->withJson($listaProdutos, 200);
        }
        else 
        {            
            return $response->withJson(array("resposta" => 'Nenhum registro encontrado.'), 200);
        }
    }
)->add(new MiddlewareApiKeyCheck());
```

Minhas dúvidas estão relacionadas com o status code do HTTP.

## Dúvidas

1. Existe algum status code HTTP que pode ser usado em situações que
   não há registros para retornar para o cliente/browser?
2. Eu posso utilizar o status code 200 nessas situações? Uma vez que a
   requisição foi bem sucedida o status deve ser `200 OK`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilize o `404`

Veja [nesse blog](https://benramsey.com/blog/2008/05/http-status-204-no-content-and-205-reset-content/). Ele explica muito bem.

Resumo dos comentários do blog sobre o retorno `204`:

1. `204 No Content` Não é extremamente útil como um código de resposta para um
   Navegador (embora, de acordo com os navegadores de especificações HTTP, precise entendê-lo como um código de resposta "não altere a exibição").
2. No entanto, o `204 No Content` é muito útil para serviços web ajax que
   Pode querer indicar sucesso sem ter que devolver algo.
   (Especialmente em casos como DELETE ou POSTs que não requerem
   comentários).

A resposta, portanto, à sua pergunta é usar `404` no seu caso. `204` é um código de resposta especializado que você normalmente **não deve retornar a um navegador em resposta a um GET**.

Os outros códigos de resposta são ainda menos apropriados do que `204` e `404`.

1. `200` devem ser devolvidos com o corpo do que você for buscado com sucesso
   . Não é apropriado quando a entidade que você está procurando não
   existir.
2. `202` é usado quando o servidor começou a trabalhar em um objeto, mas o
   O objeto ainda não está totalmente pronto. Certamente, não é o caso aqui.
3. `400` é usado em resposta a uma solicitação HTTP mal formatada (para
   Instância de cabeçalhos HTTP malformados, segmentos ordenados incorretamente, etc.).
   Isso quase certamente será tratado por qualquer estrutura que você está
   usando. Você não deve lidar com isso, a menos que você esteja escrevendo
   Seu próprio servidor a partir do zero. RFCs mais recentes agora permitem 400 para
   Ser usado para solicitações semanticamente inválidas.

Definições do [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). Você pode também ver as definições em [www.w3.org](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

[Fonte da resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746894/what-is-the-proper-rest-response-code-for-a-valid-request-but-an-empty-data)

Answer (score 1):

Eu utilizo 204 No content, já verifiquei que algumas bibliotecas também utilizam este mesmo código em situações parecidas